# cloud PaaS that supports socket programming

Tags: cloud, paas

What are the cloud PaaS that supports the opening of a socket? I browsed about various cloud services of which the GAE doesnot support socket. What are the other PaaS (both free and paid service)?
Note: languages are java,.NET mainly and any other language

Comment: You can try to use CloudBees, Heroku or Jelastic for using Java.

Comment: these three helped.Is there other alternatives?

Comment: are there any free service?

Comment: It seems that Heroku can use free unlimited time for basic.

Answer (score 1):

Socket is now supported since 1.7.2 by signing up trusted tester